# Gradient boosting for regression

Tags: cart, gradient-descent, overfitting, boosting

I was going through this 
 [this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/vip/teach/MLcourse/4_boosting/slides/gradient_boosting.pdf)  as an introduction to gradient boosting to get an overview. The algorithm described for regression is

Let n be number of samples and [image]
be the response variable.

and [image] be the model/prediction for [image]

[image] be the Loss for [image]
, Let it be least squared error. Hence negative gradient w.r.t  [image]
will be

[image]

Starting with some initial F(x),

**Iterate until convergence:**
For each [image]

calculate negative gradients [image]

Fit a regression tree h(x) to negative gradients [image]

update F([image]) [image] F([image]) + h([image])

**So** my question is , if it has to converge at a point the gradient has to be zero at that point and gradient being

[image]

ie. [image]

This would be too much overfitting infact exact fitting wouldn't it?
Why is it so? Or have I misunderstood?